How can we speed up the process of returning our lost luggage?
My girfriend and I were traveling from Stockholm to Paris with Norwegian, when we arrived at the airport in Paris her checked in bag was lost.  A bag almost identical to hers was still in the baggage claim, meaning there was probably a mixup. We went to the baggage support at the airport to report the lost bag. We filled in forms about it and sent to Norwegian. Two days later the airport called and told us the bag was found. They told us that they are going to send the bag to our hotel. We waited all week until it was time to go back home to Stockholm without getting any more information about the bag, we also emailed the airport to tell them that we did not get the bag delivered. When we went back to the airport to go back home we walked to the baggage support to get the bag, but it was not there. Apparently, they had sent the bag to our hotel and tried to call us but called the wrong number (the typed in the french country code instead of the swedish one) even though we sent both my and her number in emails to them. They told us that they were going to send the bag back home to our home address in Sweden with the next flight to Sweden and that it would be delivered in at most 24 hours, we have now waited more than two days without hearing anything new about the bag.
We tried to reach out to both the airport in Stockholm (arlanda) and Norwegian and each redirects us to the other one. Norwegian tells us that they cannot do anything at all until the bag is back. The airport phone is answered by a machine telling us to contact them by email, which we did. We got the answer that the Swedish airport had not gotten her bag and that it is probably still somewhere in Paris. We contacted the airport in Paris again and they refer us back to Norwegian. We call Norwegian again and they are still not able to help us.
We need the bag back as soon as possible, as there are some important things in there. Who can we contact about this?
There are also several things that we require compensation for:

essential things that we had to buy in Paris (we have saved every receipt).
things that we bought in Paris that we could not bring back home because we didn't have the checkin bag, wines in particular.
the cost of checking in the bag.
the day we had to spend buying new things and the time we have spent trying to get the bag back.
the days she is not able to work, due to the fact that her laptop (which is essential for her work) is in that bag.
the bag and everything in it if it does not get back.

Who should we go to about this? Norwegian can not help us with compensation until the bag is back, but neither Norwegian nor the airport can help us get it back.

Try claiming on your travel insurance?

Sadly an other example why you should never put important things in hold luggage. Laptops should never be in hold luggage, so that might give problems.

You will never get most of that compensation list. You are not supposed to put laptops or other valuables in checked bags, so you might not even get the value of the laptop, but the days you couldn't work without it? Absolutely no way. Ditto the "we couldn't bring this home" claim -- you could have bought a replacement suitcase and claimed for that, but not for what you didn't do or have.

I don’t understand what any airport has got anything to do with it? This is a matter between you and the airline and nobody else. Whether the airline outsources stuff to a ground handler is not your problem. Talk to the airline, and if they tell you to talk to anybody else remind them they are the only ones responsible and they are the ones who will have to pay compensation under the Montreal convention.

@jcaron luggage handling is mixed between airport and airline, no? Can an airline have a completely separate ground crew than the airline?

@ave This depends a lot on the airport, but in many places the airline outsources to a ground handling company which is independent from the airport. What each one does may vary (e.g. the conveyor belt system is the airport's, but putting bags on it or storing luggage which has not been reclaimed is usually not the airport, but the ground handling company. But remember: the ground handling company is working for the airline. The only one responsible for anything from the passenger's perspective is the airline.

Have you contacted the hotel to find out if they still have the bag?

The way airports around the world treat checked luggage should deter you from check in your laptop.

Your travel insurance (which I assume you have as part of your home insurance) will likely cover at least the essentials you had to buy in Paris, up to a certain amount which varies from company to company. If the bag is irretrievably lost, most Swedish travel insurances will also cover lost items, though electronics are often excluded from this category. If you have one of the higher-end corporate travel insurances and the trip counted as a business trip for your girlfriend, you may be able to get compensation for lost work days, but don’t bet too much on that.

Take a look at the Delayed baggage page for Norwegian Air:

After 5 days, our Baggage Department takes over the search from the airport.

According to their own rules, Norwegian should be managing this. It's been more than 5 days. Next time you talk to them, quote their own rules back to them.

If your bag isn’t found after 21 days, you can submit a claim for missing baggage.

Unfortunately, this is a likely outcome at this point. You you may have to sit it out and file a claim after 21 days. What and how to claim is listed in the rules as well.
As most airlines, Norwegian will likely try to weasel out of their obligation by claiming that it's not their fault ("but the bag has been found, it just lost again during delivery") and by trying to delay and ignore. You will have to be persistent and may have to threaten legal action. Fortunately Scandinavia is fairly consumer friendly.

In my experience, claims for lost luggage can be tedious but airlines are less likely to ignore them or argue about their liability as it's not based on fault and the Montreal convention does not provide for any exception due to “extraordinary circumstances” like EU 261 does.

Is Norwegian literally telling you they cannot help you or just some boilerplate “we are doing everything we can”? Ultimately you cannot force them to go out of their way but they definitely can and should try to get your luggage back to you. And after 21 days, they have to compensate you, they cannot stall forever. On the other hand, while it can be stressful, two days without news is not that long, it's not uncommon to get bags after a week or so and compensation will take even longer.
The airline is responsible for your luggage and should remain your first point of contact. It's not clear whether this is what happened here but they shouldn't just direct you to contact other parties like the airport, they will contact you as needed. It's also important to notify the airline or their representative in a timely manner to claim any sort of compensation. Norwegian explains the process on their website.
In practice, airlines hire local ground handling providers to deal with check-in, luggage, etc. This is the business that will handle the bag when it arrives and organize delivery. It is (typically) separate from the airport operator and there are often 2-3 such providers at any given airport (businesses like Dnata, Menzies, or Swissport). It doesn't hurt to talk to them and you will interact with their employees, e.g. when filing a report at the airport but it doesn't change anything to the airline's liability.
You are entitled to some monetary compensation for incidental expenses to replace the things you need during your stay (if the bag is eventually recovered) and for the loss of the luggage. There is however a maximum liability in national and international law (Montreal convention) and the airline won't accept arbitrary liability for additional damage like expensive items in the bag, lost time at work, etc. According to Your Europe, the maximum liability is currently €1300 (although I thought the Montreal convention threshold had been updated to 1299 SDR so a little more than €1500).
In this context, the reality is that lost luggage is just a regular occurrence and part of the “cost of doing business” in air transport. Handling lost luggage is expensive and airlines will frequently give up and just pay the €1300 (or whatever). There isn't really much you can do to speed things up or avoid this conclusion. In any case, the only business that can do something about it and that you should contact is Norwegian.
Because of all this, it is generally advisable to keep the most expensive items (laptops, cameras…) and hard-to-replace personal items in cabin luggage. Theoretically, it's also possible to insure your luggage for a higher value but you need to notify the airline beforehand and I have never seen any easy way to do that in a low-cost airline booking process.

It's often cheaper to put high value items on your contents insurance than pay the airline for extra baggage insurance.

Not for this time, but there are few things you can do for next flights:

better mark the baggage, so it will not be confused by other (possibly jet-lagged and/or in hurry) passengers. It should be obvious (so not just a pink name tag, but it can also help). In past stickers were used, now ribbons (around baggage, or many very bright in at each handle and zip).

tags (AirTags or similar, but one which a lot of phones): from what I get on many stories, it can help to localize and to speed up the recovery, reducing the ping-pong between different handlers at different airport. Note: FAA and EASA allows airlines to allow them (they do not have lithium battery), but each airlines can forbid them.


Note: essential items should remain in cabin, and I think it is illegal to put laptops (with lithium batteries) on checked baggage (fire hazard, considering the handling, and that lithium batteries dislikes mechanical stress). Check careful your airline rules before doing any claims on laptop, or they will have an excuses to have it stranded.

AirTags have lithium batteries.

@dhag: right, But not a rechargeable one. I forgot all things (when I looked for AirTags, but it seemed that type of batteries are not considered as the rechargeable we use on many devices (including laptops and phones). That may be a good question for the site, because it all is confusing (at least on my side).

@GiacomoCatenazzi AirTags have a lithium battery that is small enough to be exempt from most controls. Non-rechargeable lithium batteries are considered more dangerous and have more restrictions on them because they contain lithium metal, which reacts with water, compared to lithium ions in a solution for rechargeable batteries.
